# ImportError: No module named 'xlwings' using Anaconda Python Distribution in Windows 7

Tags: python, vba, xlwings

I'm trying to learn xlwings for in Windows 7 but I get the following error when importing the xlwings module in python IDLE

```
>>> import xlwings
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import xlwings
ImportError: No module named 'xlwings'
>>>
```

I installed Python using the Anaconda distribution and path variable correctly includes the site-packages
 C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages;

I'm using Excel 2013. Any ideas?

Comment: do you have more than one python version? At the top of IDLE does it say something like "Python 3.5.0 |Anaconda 2.4.0 (64-bit)" (Anaconda being the key word here)

Comment: Is there an `xlwings` directory in `site-packages`? Did you actually *install* this module, or are you just guessing it's there?

Comment: @bvmcode - yes it's showing this phrase.

Comment: @MattDMo - yes, I installed it and I also look into the site-packages folder and it's there.

Comment: I tried it again yesterday in the IDLE but it is still not working. It is still throwing that 'No module..' error after the import statement. But when I tried the sample scripts in connecting to the excel workbook (that is, completed the script first then run it using Sublime build), it worked. It is not throwing any error.

Maybe there's a bug in here?